# How do I incorporate personalization to a Bayesian ranking engine?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, conditional-probability, hierarchical-bayesian

I'm looking to quickly get smart on how to add personalization into a Bayesian-based recommendation system.

I'm using clickstream data and Bayesian statistics to estimate probabilities of purchase to rank a list of products on.  How do I incorporate user-specific history to modify my generic probabilities for a specific user?  For example, a user clicked a product in a previous site visit.  How do I estimate the purchase probability during a successive visit?  What is the standard approach here?

Looking for papers, blogs, people  that can help illuminate.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using Collaborative Filtering (CF) via Matrix Factorization in machine learning to get personalization. You can use CF w/ the Bayesian Personalized Ranking (BPR) cost function if you want to keep the Bayesian connection. See this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2618 and this intro into recommender system using machine learning: http://www.eggie5.com/99-recommender-systems